# Python Dictionaries with lists from user input how to solve this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Write a program that ask the user to enter an integer representing the number of items to be added to the stock. For these items, the program should then ask for the item barcode number and name, add them to a dictionary and print them.

Why is my code not working as expected?

```
size=input("Enter size of list")
names=[input()]
code=[int(input())]
for i in size:
    print("Enter name and code")
    names.append(input())
    code.append(int(input()))
    dict={names[i]:code[i]}

print(dict)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @MarwanMohamed, did the below answer help? If so, feel free to accept (tick on left), or ask further questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This a functioning version of your code:

```
size = input("Enter size of list")
names = []
code = []

for i in range(int(size)):
    print("Enter name and code")
    names.append(input())
    code.append(int(input()))

d = dict(zip(names, code))
print(d)
```

Among the errors that needed fixing:

- Only use `input()` in your `for` loop when you need the data.
- `i` needs to cycle through `range(int(size))` rather than a string input.
- Create the dictionary from your lists at the end via `zip`.
- Do not name variables after classes, e.g. use `d` instead of `dict`.